# Selenium headless Chrome - How to act as request from PC

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

I am using Selenium headless chrome and I get

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element
```

when it reaches `driver.find_element_by_id('mat-option-17').click()` which is true. The element is not displayed when I go headless, I checked if there is such element by using `print(driver.page_source)`. When I am using Chrome (not headless) everything is fine, the element id `id('mat-option-17')` is shown in the website source code.

Is there a way that I can run Selenium headless that the website doesn't know it is headless and the page source contain all the source as when I am using Chrome?

Comment: I figured it out myself. Changed the user agent.

Answer (score 1):

Before `driver.get(url)`, add this line of code.

```
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {"userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.53 Safari/537.36'})
```